# How to configure custom property file with encrypted properties using spring cloud?

Tags: spring, encryption, properties, cloud

The spring cloud encryption/decryption works only with application.properties file, but I have env_*.properties for each environment, how to configure those properties to be encrypted as well?

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud config server properties file work with any file name other than application.properties file. It is important you name such environment property files with a name that follows this convention:

[**spring application name**]-[**environment e.g dev, staging, etc**].[**extension**] e.g. : ***myapp-dev.properties*** or ***myapp-dev.yml*** where **my-app** corresponds to **spring.application.name** *property value*. Also make sure these files should reside in a **folder named after** **spring.application.name** value.

Comment: Something is still missing. Main class uses @PropertySource("file:config/myapp/myapp-dev.properties") and in config/application.properties I have spring.application.name=myapp property. In the dependency I have "spring-cloud-starter-config"